# Extract Expressions from Google Sheets Cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was trying to find a formula that would apply to my situation, but I couldn't understand the logic.

I have columns filled with expressions separated by commas. It's a list of tags. I'd like to do the following:

1. Extract name of the School and place into a new column.
2. Organize the list without the School into a new column.

Example:

Row 1:

```
2013, School Canyon High School, SAT Jan 2012, Summer 2013 | Canyon High School | 2013, SAT Jan 2012, Summer 2013
```

Row 2:

```
School Big Top Country Day, 2020, Algebra, School Hill High School | Big Top Country Day | Hill High School | 2020, Algebra
```

The list of items doesn't follow a specific order. Occasionally, there is more than one school listed as in row 2.

Comment: Pleasae add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result